# Find if 2 trees have similar leaves(from left to right)?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

As far as my logic goes I'm using two different arrays to store all the leafs and then compare those arrays to see if the leaves are indeed the same, but my test cases are failing (for eg. [3,5,1,6,2,9,8,null,null,7,4]
[3,5,1,6,7,4,2,null,null,null,null,null,null,9,8]). Thanks in advance!

'''
class Solution {

```
static int array1[] = new int[50];
static int array2[] = new int[50];
static int q = 0;
static int r = 0;

 public boolean compareLeaves(int arr1[], int arr2[])
 {
     for(int i = 0; i <array1.length ;i ++)
    {
        if(array1[i] != array2[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
     return true;
 }
public boolean leafSimilar(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {

    if(root1 == null || root2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(root1.left == null && root1.right == null)
    {
        array1[q] =root1.val ;
        q++;
    }

    if(root2.left == null && root2.right == null)
    {
        array2[r] =root2.val ;
        r++;
    }
    leafSimilar(root1.left,root2.left);
    leafSimilar(root1.right,root2.right);

  return compareLeaves(array1,array2);


}
```

}
'''

Comment: I don’t understand which tree `[3,5,1,6,2,9,8,null,null,7,4]` represents.

Comment: the first tree.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I don’t understand how that can represent a tree. I don’t know what the tree looks like. I don’t know which nodes it consists of and in particular not which node is a left or right child of which other node.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the arrays have different lengths but agree on the first `array1.length` elements, I believe you deem them equal (return `true`). You probably need to use `q` and `r` for determining whether the element counts are the same and how many elements to compare.
2. If both roots are `null`, I would expect that the trees should be considered equal, but you return `false`.
3. Even if `root1 == null`, you should still pick up the leaves from `root2` and vice versa.
4. I think you should do *in-order* traversal, that is, call `leafSimilar(root1.left,root2.left)` *before* you look at `root1.val` and `root2.val`. It may be that it doesn’t matter since the `val` is only considered for leaves, but I find it hard to be 100 % sure.

I may have missed something.

Using two different arrays to store all the leaves should be a sound strategy. I think it will be easier if you process each tree separately, not both trees at once.

Answer (score 0):

your program will fail for test case:

```
tree1 :   1
         /  \
      null   null

tree2:    2
        /  \
       1    null
```

clearly both trees have only one leaf node **1** but your code will fail because you are iterating on both of them identically.
you should iterate on them separately and store leaf node in the array's. And in the end check if both array have same elements no matter the order.

```
tree1 :       1
             /  \
            2    3

tree2:    1
        /  \
       3    2
```

Above two trees have same leaves, I have Updated functions to implement it correctly.

```
public int leafSimilar(TreeNode root, int arr[], int l) {

    if(root == null)
    {
        return l;
    }

    if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
    {
        arr[l] =root.val ;
        l+=1;
        return l;
    }        
    l = leafSimilar(root.left, l);
    l = leafSimilar(root.right, l);
    return l;
}

public boolean compareLeaves(int arr1[], int arr2[], int l, int r)
 {
     if( l != r ) return false;

     for(int i = 0; i <l ;i ++)
     {
       boolean flag = true;
        for(int j = 0; j <r ;j ++) {
         if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
         {
            flag = false;
            break;
         }
       }
       if( flag) return false;
    }
     return true;
 }

int l = leafSimilar(root1, arr1, 0);
int r = leafSimilar(root2, arr2, 0);
compareLeaves(arr1, arr2, l, r);
```

Also above function will fail if tree can have duplicate node. Update the compare function to count frequency of all nodes in array one and then match it with frequency of nodes in array2. It will handle duplicate nodes.

Comment: Clever answer, but since the problem may be homework, I think you’re giving too much away and leaving too little room for the questioner to write his own program and learn from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The below line of code is suggesting both the tree to follow the same path thereby, ignoring the leaves in one of the `tree1` or `tree2`.

```
if(root1 == null || root2 == null)
{
    return false;
}
```

It's better to traverse both the tree one by one. And keep on storing the leaves.

```
  public static boolean compare()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i <array1.length ;i ++)
     {
       if(array1[i] != array2[i])
       {
        return false;
       }
     } 
    return true;
  }

public void isSimilar(Node root, int flag)
{

            if(root==null)
             return;
            if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
            {
                if(flag==1)
                {
                    array1[q] =root.val ;
                    q++;
                }
                else
                {
                   array2[r] =root.val ;
                    r++; 
                }
            }

            isSimilar(root.left,flag);
             isSimilar(root.right,flag);

}
```

You have to pass a flag variable to point which array to populate. 
For ex, here 0 refer to tree1 and populate array1, and 1 refer to tree2 and populate array2 :

```
 isSimilar(root1, 0);
 isSimilar(root2, 1);
```